# 30 day overdue notification to staff

Tags: wordpress, civirules, scheduled-job

I would like to send out either an email or better an email with a report with all those members who are 30 days overdue.  I'm not wanting this to go straight to the member, but to one of my staff who will then decide who should be emailed.  This would be just once a month.

Is this possible using civi rules or scheduled jobs?  we use wordpress.

Any help gratefully received.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Reports - Membership - Lapsed memberships, you can set up your criteria and save an instance of it. On the Email Delivery tab put the staff member email. Then you can set up the Mail Reports scheduled job to run it monthly and it will email it: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/scheduled-jobs/#job_mail_report